# Asterisk "monitor" command records calls but throws away recorded files on premature hangup

Tags: asterisk, pbx

I am using the "monitor" command to record full calls. This works well, but only when the user goes through the entire callflow. I tried monitoring the recorded file size as the call progresses. Once the call starts, the file sizes start increasing (of both the "in" and "out" sides of the call). However, if the user hangs up prematurely in the middle of the call, whatever has been recorded thus far is inexplicably dropped and stubs (44 bytes) are left in its place. Any insight into why this behavior occurs will be appreciated.

I am reproducing a snippet from the dialplan I used in my extensions.conf file below:

```
exten => 7611,1,Answer()
exten => 7611,n,Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/custom/transferring_with_record_wa     rning)
exten => 7611,n,Set(GROUP()=outgoing)
exten => 7611,n,NoOp(The current group count : ${GROUP_COUNT(outgoing)})
exten => 7611,n,GotoIf($[${GROUP_COUNT(outgoing)}>1]?15)
exten => 7611,n,Set(GLOBAL(current_timestamp_7611)=${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},GMT+1,%s)})
exten => 7611,n,Set(GLOBAL(current_full_format_timestamp_7611)=${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},G     MT-8,%d%m%Y_%H%M%S)})
exten => 7611,n,NoOp(The current timestamp : ${current_timestamp_7611})
exten => 7611,n,NoOp(The last timestamp : ${last_timestamp_7611})
exten => 7611,n,GotoIf($[(${last_timestamp_7611}+20>${current_timestamp_7611})]?15)
exten => 7611,n,NoOp(All cases passed)
exten => 7611,n,Ringing()
exten => 7611,n,Wait(2)
exten => 7611,n,Monitor(wav,HALEF_audio_ext_7611_${current_full_format_timestamp_761     1})
exten => 7611,n,Dial(SIP/1200@JVXML97,,XgF(default^7611^14))
exten => 7611,n,Set(GLOBAL(last_timestamp_7611)=${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},GMT+1,%s)})
exten => 7611,n,Hangup()
exten => 7611,n,Ringing()
exten => 7611,n,Wait(2)
exten => 7611,n,Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/custom/busy_later)
exten => 7611,n,Wait(1)
exten => 7611,n,Hangup()
```

I understand that the "record" command has a "k" parameter which keeps the recorded file upon hangup, but I'm not able to find any similar functionality with the Monitor command. (I'd use "record", but I'd like to record the full call (duplex) and do it automatically, without any user input requirement).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use MixMonitor command.

Check you have permissions needed for write files.

Check debug if you unsure.

PS. using diaplan WITH n, without labels and goto to EXACT priority is very bad practice, can result hard-catchable bugs. Using GLOBAL variables without need also not so nice idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. MixMonitor does work, but mixes both channels into a single one. I was looking for a solution that retains the input and output sides of the recording, while keeping recorded files inspite of hangups. Is there any workaround that satisfies all these constraints, to your knowledge?

P.S.: And I don't think its an issue with write permissions, just so you know.

Comment: mixmonitor mix channel liek this: inbound into left channel, outbound into right channel. You can unmix or toogle any single if you need that. I can't say what you dooing wrong with monitor, use debug.

Comment: I checked the file recorded using MixMonitor, and it does not record a stereo file (so both channels are mixed into a mono file). Is there any option that I have to enable to make sure it records into a stereo file? 

Also, I still haven't found the exact problem with the Monitor command, and I'll keep looking (with debug or otherwise) -- but are you sure that this is not an Asterisk bug? I've also tried searching in other manuals and Internet fora, but none seems to talk about this problem of dropping recorded calls (retaining only the header of around 44 bytes). 

Many thanks again.

Comment: Edit: I am using Asterisk 1.8.4.4.

Comment: 1.8.4 is 3-4 year old version of LTS asterisk 1.8.* branch. You should upgrade first,after that post any bugs.